# Wrong XOR decryption

Tags: c#, xor

I've made a program that encodes a text with a random key. When the key is used, the result from the decoder is completely wrong even if I use just one letter to encode

This is the function used to encrypt/decrypt and the function that generates a random key with a determined length:

```
string XOR_String(string text, string key)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int c = 0; c < text.Length; c++)
        result.Append((char)((uint)text[c] ^ (uint)key[c % key.Length]));

    return result.ToString();
}

private static string RandomString(int Size)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    string input = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var chars = Enumerable.Range(0, Size)
                           .Select(x => input[random.Next(0, input.Length)]);
    return new string(chars.ToArray());
}
```

Decrypt:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  openFileDialog1.FileName = "data.txt";
  openFileDialog1.Title = "Open file";
  openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

  if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
      file = openFileDialog1;

      fs = new System.IO.FileStream(file.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
      reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fs);
      file_contents = reader.ReadToEnd();

      if (textBox1.Text != "")
      {
          data = XOR_String(file_contents, textBox1.Text);
          reader.Close();
      }
  }
}
```

Encrypt:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo file_info = new System.IO.FileInfo(file.FileName);
    long file_info_length = file_info.Length;
    int file_length = checked((int)file_info_length);
    String key = RandomString(file_length);
    textBox1.Text = key;
    data = XOR_String(file_contents, key);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file.FileName, data);
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't use this to secure real data.

Comment: -Magnus I know. @Dour High Arch I changed it, but same happens.

Comment: Use ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes() and then run your encryption routine on the resultant array of bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do realize that strings in the C#/.Net/CLR world are UTF-16 encoded Unicode, right?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

Only those characters at code points in the Basic Multilingual Plance (ranges U+0000– U+D7FF and U+E000–U+FFFF) are represented as a single 16-bit character.

Your random XORing of characters results in random stuff that won't round trip: it will either be invalid UTF-16 or a *surrogate pair*.

That's your problem.

If you want to encode things like this, try this:

- Use the encoding of choice to create a `byte[]` from your string to be encoded.
- XOR that.
- Convert the resulting `byte[]` ciphertext into a Base64-encoded string using [`Convert.ToBase64String()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To decode it, reverse the process:

- Convert the Base64-encoded string into a `byte[]` using [`Convert.FromBase64String()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- XOR that
- Convert the resulting plaintext `byte[]` back into a C#/.Net string using the same encoding you used in the first place.

**Edited To Note:**

Just for fun...

- A test case:

  ```
  MyNotVerySecureCrypto crypto = new MyNotVerySecureCrypto("cat" ) ;

  string plainText  = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog." ;
  string cipherText = crypto.Encrypt(plainText) ;
  string plainText1 = crypto.Decrypt(cipherText) ;

  Debug.Assert(plainText.Equals(plainText1,StringComparison.Ordinal));
  ```
- To test this code:

  ```
  public class MyNotVerySecureCrypto
  {
    private byte[]   Key      { get ; set ; }
    private Encoding Encoding { get ; set ; }

    public MyNotVerySecureCrypto( string key , Encoding encoding )
    {
      this.Encoding = encoding ;
      this.Key      = Encoding.GetBytes(key).Where( b => b != 0 ).ToArray() ;
      return ;
    }
    public MyNotVerySecureCrypto( string key ) : this ( key , Encoding.UTF8 )
    {
      return ;
    }

    public string Encrypt( string plainText )
    {
      int i = 0 ;
      byte[] octets = Encoding
                      .GetBytes(plainText)
                      .Select( b => (byte) (b^Key[(++i)%Key.Length]) )
                      .ToArray()
                      ;
      string cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(octets) ;
      return cipherText ;
    }

    public string Decrypt( string cipherText )
    {
      int i = 0 ;
      byte[] octets = Convert
                      .FromBase64String(cipherText)
                      .Select( b => (byte) (b^Key[(++i)%Key.Length]) )
                      .ToArray()
                      ;
      string plainText = Encoding.GetString( octets ) ;
      return plainText ;
    }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure each character inside your data is exactly one byte long? Only ASCII characters are one byte long, UTF characters can occupy more than one bytes. In that case you'll run into trouble. You can use following to read ASCII strings

> StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (fileStream, new
>   ASCIIEncoding());

Comment: Same happens. If I encrypt ABCDEFG, I get ;#:*/u5 as result.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the text into Base64 before encrypting it with XOR.

Using this method especially helps when exchanging XORed data between PHP & C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static byte[] EncryptOrDecrypt(byte[] text, byte[] key)
    {
        byte[] xor = new byte[text.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            xor[i] = (byte)(text[i] ^ key[i % key.Length]);
        }
        return xor;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args){
        string input;
        byte[] inputBytes;

        string inputKey;
        byte[] key;

        do
        {
            input = System.Console.ReadLine();
            inputBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input);

            inputKey = System.Console.ReadLine();
            key = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inputKey);

            //byte[] key = { 0, 0 }; if key is 0, encryption will not happen

            byte[] encryptedBytes = EncryptOrDecrypt(inputBytes, key);
            string encryptedStr = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(encryptedBytes);

            byte[] decryptedBytes = EncryptOrDecrypt(encryptedBytes, key);
            string decryptedStr = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedBytes);

            System.Console.WriteLine("Encrypted string:");
            System.Console.WriteLine(encryptedStr);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Decrypted string:");
            System.Console.WriteLine(decryptedStr);

        } while (input != "-1" && inputKey != "-1");
        //test:
        //pavle
        //23
        //Encrypted string:
        //BRD_W
        //Decrypted string:
        //pavle
    }
```

Comment: The problems with this answer are: (a) you use only the lower byte of each character (see Nicholas' answer) and (b) your encryption is not reversible - you remove all characters from the ciphertext where the plaintext happens to be equal to the key; you will not be able to descrypt this again.

Comment: @KlausGütter i must say you are right but you are not right:  (a) I am using only the lower byte because the higher byte is 0. And when you encrypt it, text will have spaces between letters, and the decryption whit same algorithm would not be possible and (b) **it** **works**.
I will edit main slightly so you can try algorithm easily...

Comment: (b) no it does not work; try input = "pavle" and key = "2a": Encrypted string: BD W, Decrypted string:p%?6

Comment: You are right, my tests didn't show that error. Thanks! I corrected it :D

Comment: Sorry for insisting, but this still won't work. `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(encryptedBytes)` assumes that encryptedBytes is a valid unicode string which is in no way guaranteed. Usually, one would use Base64 encoding instead.

Comment: Hahaha this is just silly... This code is not perfect, but it works just fine. If someone is using Base64 encoding, logic will stay the same, but he would need to change converting...

Comment: I would not call it silly. What does `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(new byte[] { 0x00, 0xD8 }))` give you? Certainly not `new byte[] { 0x00, 0xD8 }`again. Many people search StackOverflow for their questions and may just take the code from one of the answers. So you have a certain responsibility.

Comment: Yes, but if you use `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(thatNewBytes);` you will get the same string. And if you use it for encrypting/decrypting strings, that is what matters. If you use it for bytes, there is no reason to convert them to Unicode... 
`byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x00, 0xD8 };
            string someStr = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
            byte[] newBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(someStr);
            string someStr1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(newBytes);
            Console.WriteLine(someStr.Equals(someStr1, StringComparison.Ordinal)); //true`

Comment: That's true but irrelevant. You will never be able to get new byte[] { 0x00, 0xD8 } back. Using Encoding.Unicode.GetString/GetBytes as a means to get a reversible representation of binary data is just not correct. I propose we end this discussion here.

Comment: Yes, i understand you, but here i use Unicode encoding just for easier testing in main.... L learned from this discussion and we will end it, but if you know, is there a way to do that converting and keep the same bytes?